# how can i make dataframe from text with spaces in r?

Tags: r, dataframe, text, rounding

i have below text and i wanna make a dataframe
below text aaa column have list and numbers and numbers have
spaces between them.. when i tried fread(a) it outputs not what 
i wanted..

```
a<-"
   number    aaa
    1        list(list(10.4444, 11.3333, 12.3333))
    2        list(list(10.3333, 11.3333, 12.3333, 13.3333, 14.3333, 15.3333))
    3        list(list(20.3333))
    4        list(list())
"
```

i want dataframe outputs below (numbers is needed to rounded by 2)

```
number        aaa 
    1        10.44,11.33,12.33
    2        10.33,11.33,12.33,13.33,14.33,15.33
    3        20.33
    4        NA
```

could anybody help me ? thank you in advance !

Comment: If the file is a tab separated .txt you can import with `b <- read.delim2("tmp.txt", stringsAsFactors = F)`, then use the answer by @Onyambu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
b = read.table(text=gsub('\\b(\\w+) ','\\1:',a),h=T,sep=":",strip.white = T,stringsAsFactors = F)
b$aaa = lapply(parse(text=b[,2]),function(x)unlist(eval(x)))

b
  number                                                  aaa
1      1                            10.4444, 11.3333, 12.3333
2      2 10.3333, 11.3333, 12.3333, 13.3333, 14.3333, 15.3333
3      3                                              20.3333
4      4                                                 NULL
```

Note that `aaa` above is a list within the dataframe and the values are numeric:

on the other hand you can do:

```
read.table(text = gsub('(?m)(?<=:).*\\(|\\).*','',gsub('\\b(\\w+) ','\\1:',a),perl=T),sep = ":",na.strings = "",h=T,stringsAsFactors = F,strip.white = T)

  number                                                  aaa
1      1                            10.4444, 11.3333, 12.3333
2      2 10.3333, 11.3333, 12.3333, 13.3333, 14.3333, 15.3333
3      3                                              20.3333
4      4                                                 <NA>
```

Comment: thanks ! could you do more about round ? i need aaa column numbers are rounded by 2.

Comment: @jerryhan sure. Instead of the `lapply` above, you can do `lapply(parse(text=b[,2]),function(x){m=unlist(eval(x));if(!length(m))NA else round(m,2)})`

Answer (score 0):

The `data.table` variant

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[,.(number,gsub("\\)\\)","",gsub("list\\(","",aaa)))]

   number                                              V2
1:      1                         10.4444,11.3333,12.3333
2:      2 10.3333,11.3333,12.3333,13.3333,14.3333,15.3333
3:      3                                         20.3333
4:      4
```

To obtain the rounded numbers you can try

```
temp1<-strsplit(gsub("\\)\\)","", gsub("list\\(", "", df$aaa)), split = ",") # removing characters list( and )) and split the result
temp2 <- lapply(temp1, function(x) round(as.numeric(x),2)) # converting to numeric and rounding

data.frame(number= df$number,
      new= unlist((lapply(temp2,paste,collapse = ", "))))

  number                                      new
1      1                      10.44, 11.33, 12.33
2      2 10.33, 11.33, 12.33, 13.33, 14.33, 15.33
3      3                                    20.33
4      4
```